# How to reload present view controller swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two Present view controllers. The thing i want to do is when the second Present view controller is dismissed it will automatically reload the first present view controller(Table view). note: first view controller holds a table view, basically i want to reload the table view of first controller.
ViewWillAppear code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableViewReloadFromCreateProductVC()
}
func tableViewReloadFromCreateProductVC () {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Calling from second view controller code:

```
        SecondViewController.tableViewReloadFromCreateProductVC()
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: On which line you are getting the error ? and are you sure your viewWillAppear method is called ?

Comment: In this line: SecondViewController.tableViewReloadFromCreateProductVC()

Comment: Before calling the viewWillAppear method the error appears

Comment: just remove that line and check your viewWillAppear method is called .its because you are not calling it right.

Comment: Just removed that line but when the second present view controller is dismissed viewWillAppear is not called

Comment: i have updated my answer hope it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FirstViewController calling 2nd view controller

```
@IBAction func CallSecondViewButton(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewControllerIdentifier") as! YourViewController
                    
                    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
```

just write the code in viewWillAppear() method of the view controller that you want to reload like this

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        
        //perform api call if any
        yourTableView.reloadData()
        
    }
```

2nd view controller

```
@IBAction func CloseButton(_ sender: Any) {
        
        
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        
    }
```

after dissmissing the viewWillAppear method of firstViewController will autometically called.
The First two snippets are for first view controller and the last one is for second view controller

Comment: I have tried this but  throws an error, error:- found nil while unwrapping an optional value

Comment: can you share some of your code so i can identify the problem also the error line number

Comment: Take a look at my snippet

Comment: Not helping, just closed the second view controller but not reloading my table view

Comment: Strange this works for me 100% of the time.the viewwillAppear method is called or not by this method ?Also have you presented the 2nd view controller by my method.

Comment: viewwillAppear is called but table view is not reloading

Comment: ok half of your problem is solved then , now make sure you are updating the tableview data before calling the reloadData() function

Comment: i have to call my api again inside the viewWillappear method and then the problem solved. You helped a lot thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Reloading the entire table view could sometimes be costly and it also sounds like you're making an API call as well so unless you want your table view to be reloaded and the API call made every time the view controller becomes visible whether or not you've made changes to it, you want the reloading to be done only when it's necessary.

You can try it in a few different ways:

```swift
class CreateProductVC: UITableViewController {
    @IBAction func presentSecondVC() {
        if let secondVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SecondVC") as? SecondViewController {
            secondVC.delegate = self
            present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: CreateProductVC?
    
    @IBAction func dismissSecondVC() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.delegate?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

or

```swift
class CreateProductVC: UITableViewController {
    @IBAction func presentSecondVC() {
        if let secondVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SecondVC") as? SecondViewController {
            
            secondVC.isDismissed = { [weak self] in
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            
            present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var isDismissed: (() -> Void)?
    
    @IBAction func dismissSecondVC() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.isDismissed?()
        }
    }
}
```

or if you want more fine-grained control over what to do with the new data:

```swift
protocol ReloadVC {
    func reload(_ value: String)
}

class CreateProductVC: UITableViewController, ReloadVC {
    var dataSource: [String]! {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func presentSecondVC() {
        if let secondVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SecondVC") as? SecondViewController {
            
            secondVC.delegate = self
            
            present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func reload(_ value: String) {
        dataSource.append(value)
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: ReloadVC?
    
    @IBAction func dismissSecondVC() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            let someValue = "Some Value"
            self.delegate?.reload(someValue)
        }
    }
}
```